# Is there a way to resize Firefox's window width to 100px? Or is there any other browser that let me have window width under 100px?

Tags: javascript

My work requires 100 windows next to each other having the smallest sizes possible.
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PilKs.png

a. For height, it is limited by the message box, which I reduced to 88px by adding this in the userChrome.css

```
* { 
    font-size: 3pt !important;
    font-family: Leelawadee !important; 
}
```

This is the smallest legible font size and font for me, so I'm satisfied with 88px height.

b. For width, I added this in the userChrome.css

```
#main-window:not([chromehidden~="toolbar"]) {
    min-width:20px!important;
}
```

But Firefox's windows refused to be reduced under 126px, which I'm very frustrated about. I know the limit is 100 pixels, so I just need to reduce my window width to 100 pixels, it would help me a lot. So,

1. Can you suggest a way to reduce the message box size while increasing the font size?
2. Can you tell me how to reduce window width to 100px?

Answer (score 0):

1) for font size you can use 'font-size' in css and specify the size that you want, if you have a box as a div element give an id to it and in css specify a width:

```
<div id="box">Something</div>
```

css:

```
#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
```

keep in mind that for size and positioning of an elements is recommended to use a framework like bootstrap.

2) You can use window object that has this methods

- window.open
- window.resizeTo

with these two methods you can open a new window and resize it

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying but I'm totally noob. Can you check this image:
https://i.imgur.com/Yg2St2U.png

The message box appears when I press Redeem button. You can check the message box here: https://m.mobilelegends.com/en/codexchange

=> What should I write into userChrome.css to reduce the message box size while having more legible font size?